# I get "Unexpected token in JSON at position 0" when try to use readfilesync in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm using nodejs fs.readFileSync to load a json and turn it to js array but I get this error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\myProjects 4 98\project1\crop.js:13:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

but if I save the exact string as a variable inside my code, there is no error, so I think my JSON syntax is ok. 
here is my code, if I comment out fs.readfilesync and uncomment next line, the problem disappears, json.txt and the string below are exactly same!

how can I load the json from external file?

```
var json = fs.readFileSync('json.txt', 'utf8');
//var json = '[{"Name":"image1.png","crops":[{"x":0,"y":53.29014916901091,"width":880,"height":502.44997787924575}]},{"Name":"image2.png","crops":[{"x":0,"y":8.616125016979977,"width":498,"height":350.3890840238524},{"x":0,"y":371.92939656630233,"width":498,"height":139.29402110784292}]},{"Name":"image3.jpg","crops":[{"x":0,"y":12.711224291602823,"width":232,"height":60.211062433908104},{"x":0,"y":65.56315687247772,"width":232,"height":109.04892418585581}]},{"Name":"image44.png","crops":[{"x":0,"y":124.83500957409233,"width":548,"height":453.5145284527152},{"x":0,"y":225.9671692290532,"width":548,"height":178.56146939079028}]}]'
```

this is my json.txt

```
[{"Name":"image1.png","crops":[{"x":0,"y":53.29014916901091,"width":880,"height":502.44997787924575}]},{"Name":"image2.png","crops":[{"x":0,"y":8.616125016979977,"width":498,"height":350.3890840238524},{"x":0,"y":371.92939656630233,"width":498,"height":139.29402110784292}]},{"Name":"image3.jpg","crops":[{"x":0,"y":12.711224291602823,"width":232,"height":60.211062433908104},{"x":0,"y":65.56315687247772,"width":232,"height":109.04892418585581}]},{"Name":"image44.png","crops":[{"x":0,"y":124.83500957409233,"width":548,"height":453.5145284527152},{"x":0,"y":225.9671692290532,"width":548,"height":178.56146939079028}]}]
```

my whole node app!

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Jimp = require('jimp'); 

// User-Defined Function to read the images 
var json = fs.readFileSync('json2.txt', 'utf8');
//var json = '[{"Name":"image1.png","crops":[{"x":0,"y":53.29014916901091,"width":880,"height":502.44997787924575}]},{"Name":"image2.png","crops":[{"x":0,"y":8.616125016979977,"width":498,"height":350.3890840238524},{"x":0,"y":371.92939656630233,"width":498,"height":139.29402110784292}]},{"Name":"image3.jpg","crops":[{"x":0,"y":12.711224291602823,"width":232,"height":60.211062433908104},{"x":0,"y":65.56315687247772,"width":232,"height":109.04892418585581}]},{"Name":"image44.png","crops":[{"x":0,"y":124.83500957409233,"width":548,"height":453.5145284527152},{"x":0,"y":225.9671692290532,"width":548,"height":178.56146939079028}]}]'
// '[{"Name":"image2.png","crops":[{"x":0,"y":7.180104180816647,"width":498,"height":348.953063187689},{"x":0,"y":359.00520904083237,"width":498,"height":150.78218779714956}]},{"Name":"image4 - Copy.png","crops":[{"x":0,"y":140.63690952017996,"width":548,"height":404.5286386198435}]}]';
var array = JSON.parse(json);

 async function main() { 
     for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
       var imagePath = 'E:\\myProjects 4 98\\project1\\assets\\Imgs\\' + array[i].Name;
         for (var j = 0; j < array[i].crops.length; j++){
            const image = await Jimp.read(imagePath);
            var imageName = array[i].Name.replace(/\.(.*?)$/g, '');
             var cropName = imageName + '_' + j;
            image.crop(array[i].crops[j].x, array[i].crops[j].y, array[i].crops[j].width, array[i].crops[j].height)
            .write(cropName + '.jpg'); 

         }
     }
} 
main(); 
console.log("Image Processing Completed");
```

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). You haven't given us enough information to answer the question above. Assuming the file really contains valid JSON, then `JSON.parse(json)` will work.  Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: That object works fine when I load it with `.readFileSync()` and parse it. You didn't really post any of your code however. Also, I assume that the file does *not* include the single-quote characters around the JSON text.

Comment: The json string looks fine, did you use `JSON.parse`?

Comment: Ah, there's a zero-width space character in your file. You probably cut-and-pasted it from somewhere.

Comment: yes I have pased it from someWhere else, but where is this zero-width space? and even using the original json.txt draws same problem

Comment: The zero-width space is right there in the error message you posted. Edit your file with a text editor and delete and re-type the first few characters.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a BOM at your json.txt.

```
  if (json.charCodeAt(0) === 0xfeff) {
    json = json.substr(1);
  }
```

Add above lines to remove BOM automatically or just save your file without BOM.

Answer (score 0):

Could be characters you don't see in plain text. Maybe the encoding is wrong

Comment: when I use ctrl+A, ctrl + C , and copy paste the exact code from json.txt to my node app and save it as json variable, the code works

Comment: It's not the same